How to Resolve Issues with Server-Side Rendering in Nuxt 3?
I am using Nuxt 3 and Pinia, after refreshing the page it logs me out, but after removing part of the code from the auth.js file:
 // If the user is not logged in, redirect to the login page
    if (!user.value) {
        return router.push(`/admin/sprawy-w-toku/`);
    }

    // If the user is not logged in, redirect to the login page
    const adminUserIds = [
        
    ];

    // Array of user IDs who have access to the admin panel
    if (!adminUserIds.includes(user.value.id)) {
        return router.push('/'); // Redirect to the page when the user does not have permissions
    }

, it no longer logs me out.
My file auth.js:
// middleware/adminAuth.js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const { $supabase } = useNuxtApp();
    const user = useSupabaseUser();
    const router = useRouter();

    // If the user is not logged in, redirect to the login page
    if (!user.value) {
        return router.push(`/admin/sprawy-w-toku/`);
    }

    // Array of user IDs who have access to the admin panel
    const adminUserIds = [
        
    ];

    // Check if the logged-in user's ID is on the list of admins
    if (!adminUserIds.includes(user.value.id)) {
        return router.push('/'); // Redirect to the page when the user does not have permissions
    }

});

I tried removing parts of the code, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
